# Regression Confidence

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I have the following challenge: I have to create a regression model with multiple independent variables. When the model is put in production, it can happen that I get completely new values in my independent variable, which my model didn't know when it was trained. The predicted value would have a very high error. In that case I would have to acquire new training data (costly) and retrain the model.

-> Are there any approaches to detect a prediction which is not reliable because my model wasn't trained for and I should better retrain the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the nature of these variables?

Answer (score 1):

I might include a preprocessing step that deals with values well outside the range the model was trained on. Hopefully these are very rare (if not, then one might say you should train the model with more representative data).

You might set upper/lower bounds for each variable (e.g., +/- 3sd) and then replace them with NA to ensure the model is 'undefined' for such cases (*for models that require complete feature sets). Alternatively you could replace them with a constant or suitably large/small value, but that kind of hack isn't really ideal.

This basically amounts to outlier treatment you could also build into the training set just to keep everything kosher.

Comment: I was thinking about setting upper/lower bounds for each variable, but I thought there is a better statistical way, or some best practice behind that. 
Of course in an ideal world I would use more data, but imagine that in some cases acquiring training data is very expensive, I would only want to get more training data if absolutely necessary. So I thought there is some way that tells me "Be careful the confidence of that prediction is very low, because I have never seen data in that range, better get more training data in this area"

Comment: @MikeHuber Alternatively just let the model do its thing. Even extreme values can be handled for well described models.

Comment: Okay but this is just an assumption. If new data points arrive they could have a different relationship to my target value. One idea I had is to calculate the distance every time a make a prediction to my closest training data points to get an idea if I had enough training data for the prediction. But I thought that would be a common problem with some established approaches?